# Mediawiki strange string on pages

Tags: mediawiki, error, code

I upgraded from MediaWiki 1.23 to 1.24.2, but at the end of the upgrade, the pages started to show a strange string, by instance - "COS" at the top of the pages. I tried to inspect the page code to see if there was anything strange, but the three letters doesn't appear on the code.

Comment: Those 3 letters certainly appear in the HTML source code. Are your source files encoded OK? Encoded BOM??

Comment: It does appear in the source code...

Comment: Did you remove the entire MediaWiki directory before putting the newly downloaded code in place? If not, how did you make sure your installation was not cracked?